# Android Monitor says: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I am trying to get Scanresults of wifi from one class to an other.

this is my first class:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // Wenn Hardware scan durchzogen wurde (wegen -->SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
        String wifiList1;
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        wifiList1=wifiList.toString();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Scan für AP Umgebung fertig", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("onReceive","ausgeführt");
        Log.v("ScanResults",wifiList1);
    }

    public List<ScanResult> getWifiList(){
        return wifiList;
    }
```

And this one here is the other class, where I want to use my data from getScanResults(), which I am saving here in wifilist as you can see.

```
public StringBuilder getAParound(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    DemoApp wf2 = new DemoApp();
    DemoApp.WifiReceiver wf = wf2.new WifiReceiver();

    for (int i = 0; i< wf.getWifiList().size(); i++) {  // At this line Android Monitor says Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        sb.append(Integer.toString(i + 1) + ". ");
        sb.append(wf.getWifiList().get(i).toString());
        Log.v("getAParound","ausgeführt");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

I can see the results in `Log.v("ScanResults",wifiList1);` without any problems.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: The problem is with getWifiList.size(); You first create a new `WifiReceiver` and try to read the data of the list while it's not initialized. You should read the data when you receive data and/or initialize like: `wifiList = new ArrayList()<>;` in the `WifiReceiver` as a field. This is all i can read from your code snippets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! What do you mean by not initialized? With wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults(); it isn´t done? I am confused. Could you write the portion of code please?

Comment: @Okey That line would do it, but you haven't called `onReceive()` yet, so `wifiList` is still null.

Comment: @Andreas It is called. I can see the toast message on my screen and the Log.v("ScanResults",wifiList1); with filled results! Here is a example from what I see in Android Monitor: V/ScanResults: [SSID: eduroam, BSSID: 1c:aa:07:43:d4:d0, capabilities: [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS], level: -59, frequency: 2432, timestamp: 187981755591, distance: ?(cm), distanceSd: ?(cm), passpoint: no, status: 16, ChannelBandwidth: 0, centerFreq0: 0, centerFreq1: 0, 80211mcResponder: is not supported, SSID: eduroam, BSSID: 1c:aa:07:43:d4:df, capabilities: [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS], level: -63,

Comment: @Okey But is it called in the few nanoseconds between `wf = wf2.new WifiReceiver()` and `wf.getWifiList().size()`?

Comment: @Andreas No. It is called about 4 seconds after on create, beacuse I put there mainWifi.startScan(); . And when the scan is finished it calls the on Receive method().

Comment: @Okey So there is your answer. Right after creating the `WifiReceiver` instance, you *immediately* enter a `for` loop, trying to iterate the `wifiList`, even though you *know* that it is not yet initialized. And you wonder why you get NPE???

Comment: @Andreas No, because I enter my for loop about after 25 seconds. I measure the speed download and upload before in my app

Comment: @Okey I'm sorry, but there is a single blank line between `wf = wf2.new WifiReceiver()` and the `for` loop. In what world does it take 25 seconds to execute a blank line?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you dont Instanced the wifiList, try to use 'new' key word to create a instance of the list in the constructor method maybe.

Like This:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private List<ScanResult> wifiList;

// This is a construtcor
public WifiReceiver(){
    wifiList = new List<ScanResult>() // Here you crerate the object
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    // Wenn Hardware scan durchzogen wurde (wegen -->SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
    String wifiList1;
    wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
    wifiList1=wifiList.toString();
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Scan für AP Umgebung fertig", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("onReceive","ausgeführt");
    Log.v("ScanResults",wifiList1);
}

public List<ScanResult> getWifiList(){
    return wifiList;
}
```

its is because the object types defualt value is 'null'

Comment: How do you mean that? I am new to programming, so I am sry for these newbie questions!

Comment: Its ok, I mean your variable 'wifiList' is not receive any value, at least in the code you showed, so you have to do something like this: wifiList = new List<ScanResult>();

Comment: I tried like you sad but, // This is a construtcor
        public WifiReceiver(){
            wifiList2 = **new List<ScanResult>();** // Here you crerate the object
        }  /n Android Studio gives following error for the part I made bold: List is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: Sorry, my bad, try this: wifiList = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();